# Silverlight databinding, perplexing issue

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-5.0

I've been doing Silverlight development for awhile now, and I was pretty sure that I had pretty good handle on figuring thing out.  This one has me completely baffled however...[image]

As you can see, the very property that Silverlight is reporting an error on, is directly where it should be!  Any ideas?  I've also found my Visual Studio being really slow, and I'm thinking a resinstall is in order.  I just got a new laptop Lenovo W520, with a graphics accelerator.  Not sure what is going on... any ideas would be appreciated!

Regards,
Richard

Comment: Can we see the code for the property?  I'm wondering if it's non-public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess: FinancialContracts is not actually a public property? It must be both public and a property.

Comment: DOH! Didn't even cross my mind.... some days I wonder why I love this job so much!